# Проблемы с кодировкой c# sendkeys

Tags: c#, клавиатура

Если sendkeys'ом отправлять такую строку:

```
SendKeys.send("Привет");
```

То всё работает прекрасно.

Но если же сделать вот так:

```
SendKeys.send("Привет, world");
```

То начинается ужас из "????" ИЛИ "цщкдв".

Что с этим можно сделать? Как отправить "Привет, world" нормально?

Comment: Просто посылайте в отдельном send

Answer (score 2):

Это никак не связано с кодировкой. Дело в том, что в Windows раскладка клавиатуры задается на уровне потоков. По некоторым причинам, *SendKeys* работает некорректно, если для потока, которому принадлежит целевое окно, установлена другая раскладка, чем для текущего потока - либо для русских, либо для английских букв будет генерироваться сообщение с несоответствующим скан-кодом.

Эту проблему можно решить, изменив раскладку текущего потока так, чтобы они совпадали:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsTest1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);        

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetKeyboardLayout(uint thid);        

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern IntPtr ActivateKeyboardLayout(IntPtr hkl, uint Flags);


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process pr = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad")[0];
            IntPtr hwnd = pr.MainWindowHandle;            

            //получение идентификатора потока целевого окна
            uint dummy = 0;
            uint thid = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out dummy);

            //смена раскладки клавиатуры на раскладку целевого окна
            IntPtr id = GetKeyboardLayout(thid); 
            ActivateKeyboardLayout(id, 0);           

            SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);//передаем фокус окну
            SendKeys.Send("Hello, мир");//теперь должно сработать
        }

    }    

}
```